# Get foreign key related objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 3 models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class AppealForm(models.Model):
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.report_form_name

class Appeal(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    appeal_form = models.ForeignKey(AppealForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    appeal_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    applicant_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    applicant_second_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    appeal_body = models.TextField()
```

Objects of models:

**Organization**
|#|name|
|-|-|
|1|Apple|
|2|Samsung|
|3|Dell|

**AppealForm**
|#|form_name|
|-|-|
|1|Written|
|2|Oral|

**Appeal**
|#|organization|appeal_form|appeal_number|applicant_first_name|applicant_second_name|date|appeal_body|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|1|Apple|Written|abc1|Oliver|Jake|06/22/2023|Test appeal body text|
|2|Apple|Oral|abc12|Jack|Connor|05/22/2023|Test appeal body text|
|3|Apple|Oral|abc123|Harry|Callum|04/22/2023|Test appeal body text|
|4|Dell|Written|abc1234|Charlie|William|03/22/2023|Test appeal body text|
|5|Dell|Oral|abc12345|George|Reece|02/22/2023|Test appeal body text|

**I want to generate a table like this below querying from Organization model:**
| # | Organization | Total amount of appeals | Written appeals amount | Oral appeals amount |
| - | --- |--- |--- |--- |
| 1 | Apple | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Samsung | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Dell | 2 | 1 | 1 |

*How the query will look like?*
Thanks in advance!

==========================================

**UPDATED:**

*filters.py*

```
class AppealFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    appeal__date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ['appeal__date ']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) here like this:

```
Organization.objects.annotate(total_appeals=Count('appeal'), written_appeals=Count('appeal', filter=Q(appeal__appeal_form__form_name="written")),
oral_appeals=Count('appeal', filter=Q(appeal__appeal_form__form_name="Oral")))
```

Here I am [reverse querying](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) from Organization to Appeal and attaching the count of Appeals for each organization. I am using [filter on annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) to separate Oral and Written appeals.

Comment: Thank you very much Arnab! It works, but there is another problem. I used django-filter package to filter the table by Appeal model's date attribute. When I try other dates some  organizations are being returned, not all organizations. Yeah, it is because there are no appeals for these not returned organization. But how to return also the rest of the organizations with null value? I'll update my question with filter.py now.

Comment: I am bit unclear about the organizations with date issue. I think it is better to ask a new question with little more details. :)

Comment: I think I got you :)

Comment: Hi Arnab, hope you are doing well! I have posted another question relating to making a query in my page again recently, could you open please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76537738/how-to-make-complex-query-chartjs-and-django