# How to make a complex query? | ChartJS and Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, chart.js

I have a chart created using Chart JS library below:

[image: Chart JS]

My models.py below:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class AppealForm(models.Model):
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.report_form_name

class Appeal(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    appeal_form = models.ForeignKey(AppealForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    appeal_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    applicant_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    applicant_second_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    appeal_body = models.TextField()
```

Script of Chart JS used to create choosen line graph:

```
new Chart(chartTwo, {
         type: 'line',
         data: {
            labels: ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'],
            datasets: [
                  {
                  label: 'written',
                  data: [
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                  ],
                  borderColor: "green",
                  backgroundColor: "green",
                  },
                  {
                  label: 'oral',
                  data: [
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                     Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                  ],
                  borderColor: "blue",
                  backgroundColor: "blue",
                  },
            ]
         },
         options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
            y: {
                  min: -20,
                  max: 120,
            }
            }
         },
      })
```

**Qestion:** *how the query will look like for this graph using AppealForm model?*

P.s. I want to get a count of each AppealForm model object by month from the start of the year till the end. This year is not ended yet, so for the rest of the month I want to get 0 value to paste responsively to the graph.

====================================================

UPDATED:

objects of Organization model:

| # | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Samsung |

objects of AppealForm model:

| # | form_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | written |
| 2 | oral |

objects of Appeal model:

*there are more appeals to show here, but it does not play a role in the query I want*

UPDATED question: How to query AppealForm (AppealForm.objects.etc...) table in order to get data for the line graph above?

Comment: You mean Appeal? Count of appeal objects by month, in current year, padded with zeros for future months?

Comment: Hi! I have updated my question, does it make a sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to count objects of type appeal in the current year, per month, with those related to an `appeal_form` `form_name="written"` separate from `appeal_form__form_name="oral"`?

What I know works, counting by month. I've tested this with a model of my own called PO (purchase order) with field date just like your Appeal.

```
>>> qs1 = PO.objects.filter( date__year=2023)
>>> result = qs1.aggregate( **{ 
        f'{x+1:02}' : Count('date', filter=Q(date__month=x+1) )
        for x in range(12) })
>>> result
{'01': 6, '02': 3, '03': 3, '04': 3, '05': 1, '06': 0, '07': 0, '08': 0, '09': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0, '12': 0}

>>> [ x[1] for x in sorted( result.items())]
[6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

A simple `result.values()` gives the same list but that's taking a lot on trust with respect to the ordering of queryset results. Better to explicitly sort them as you require.

Also it was a typo not to put `f'M{x+1:02}'` so the key starts with an alphabetic character. But, it worked! Who knew Python allowed that?

Now, with your one you could run two similar queries:

```
qs1 = Appeal.objects.filter( date__year=2023, appeal_form__form_name='oral')  
oral_results = qs1.aggregate( **{ ... 
qs2 = Appeal.objects.filter( date__year=2023, appeal_form__form_name='written')  
written_results = qs2.aggregate( **{ ...
```

Or you could put the criterion into the Q objects (24  of them) and do it all with one query and disentangle them afterwards. The code won't be nearly as clear, and longer.

I'm not a DB expert and I've no idea whether this is efficient. For my purposes, I'm not working on enough DB rows for PostgreSQL to even blink, and these reports get done once per month!

Incidentally it's quite easy to do last 12 months with this technique

```
>>> from datetime import date

>>> qs3 = PO.objects.filter( date__range=(date(2022,6,1), date(2023,5,31)) )   
>>> months = [(2022,x) for x in range(6,13)] + [ (2023,x) for x in range(1,6)]
>>> months
[(2022, 6), (2022, 7), (2022, 8), (2022, 9), (2022, 10), (2022, 11), (2022, 12), (2023, 1), (2023, 2), (2023, 3), (2023, 4), (2023, 5)]

 >>> qs3.aggregate( **{ f'{x[0]}_{x[1]:02}' : Count('date', filter=Q(date__month=x[1]) ) for x in months })
{'2022_06': 2, '2022_07': 5, '2022_08': 0, '2022_09': 6, '2022_10': 4, '2022_11': 1, '2022_12': 3, '2023_01': 6, '2023_02': 3, '2023_03': 3, '2023_04': 3, '2023_05': 1}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! It gives an error `free variable 'Count' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope` when I tried 
`qs1 = AppealForm.objects.filter(appeal__date__year=2023, form_name='written')` after
`res = qs1.aggregate( **{f'{x+1:02}':Count('appeal__date', filter=Q(appeal__date__month=x+1)) for x in range(12)})`

Comment: Did you import `from django.db.models import Count, Q`? The >>> stuff is copy/pasted out of ./manage.py shell

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't operating on `Appeal.objects...`? It's efficient following ForeignKey relations from the object which defines them. Not sure what happens if you do the reverse.

Comment: Yes, for I have imported all the libs you defined. Could you show me your query within Appeal model, please?!

Comment: Ahhh, I got it it was there sorry) Anyway it gives error like above `free variable 'Count' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope`. The code is accurately indented, imported all libs and removed >>>...

Comment: From the shell all your job is working perfectly, what to do? :)

Comment: My mistake, silly headache. I imported Count in the top of of the file and in the function where the query goes. Second import statement in the function was under the query you provided, so it decided that Count is not imported before. Sorry and thank you very much for your time!!!